# Is it true that if $ -p \equiv -1 \pmod q $, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod q $?

Tags: congruences

Is it true that if $ -p \equiv -1 \pmod q $, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod q $? 
p and q are prime numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. $-p = -1 + nq$, so $p = 1-nq = 1 + (-n) \times q$.

Comment: Note also that as Patrick Stevens' answer makes clear, this is true even if we do not require that $p$ and $q$ be prime.